# How to disable touchpad click on Acer Aspire 5742z

Tags: unity, aspire

I have an Acer Aspire 5742Z using Ubuntu operating system - how do I disable the touch-pad click

Comment: You have tagged your question with "unity". If it is because you are using unity you might want to mention it in the question -- makes it easier for people to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2):

1/Paste this code in a file named (randomly ) touchpad.sh file :

```
#!/bin/sh

#
#    My touchpad for some reason is being reported as a wheel mouse instead of a touchpad so
#    that is the string I search for to get the deviceid
#
DEVICE_ID=`xinput -list | grep -i "wheel mouse" | grep id= | sed 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' `

if xinput -list-props $DEVICE_ID | grep "Device Enabled" | grep "1$" > /dev/null
then
    xinput set-int-prop $DEVICE_ID "Device Enabled" 8 0
else
    xinput set-int-prop $DEVICE_ID "Device Enabled" 8 1
fi
```

2/ enable executing

```
sudo chmod 755 touchpad.sh
```

3/System --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts
Create a shortcut to execute this file with command similar `bash /path/to/sh/file/touchpad.sh`

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this : I have tried to access system>mouse and select the touchpad tab. There isn't one!

I have searched the internet and tried changing xorg.conf. This does not work. I am using ubuntu 10.04 and have also tried with 10.10

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu, the way this site works is you continuously update your question with information then people will start submitting answers. After you've edited it, feel free to delete this answer, thanks!

Comment: Please read also the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq).

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this problem by upgrading to ubuntu 10.10. Ian had not upgraded but posted that the system had been upgraded expecting the problem to still exist.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes looking for a solution to a similar problem:

You could try installing this package called `gpointing-device-settings` from the repositories. Then open up **System->Preferences->Pointing Devices** and configure your touchpad/mouse however you wish to.